# Can I print the date object into the flexdashboard title?

Tags: r, date, r-markdown, dashboard, flexdashboard

I do not know whether there is a way to print a date object that appears into one of the '''r ''' chuncks in flexdashboard.

this is the flexdashboard title:

```
---
title: 'r param$title
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: simplex
    vertical_layout: scroll
    orientation: rows
param:
  title: paste0( "Metrics from_date_to_date)" 
  from_date_to_date: print(from_date_to_date)

---
```

And this is my date object:

```
> from_date_to_date <- data_metrics$month_data_generated %>%
+   unique()
> from_date_to_date
[1] "2023-04-15 to 2023-05-16"
```

Obviously, as wrong as it is, I've used the r coding language at the heading of the rmarkdown to show what I want. Is there a way to print my date object from a chunk into the title?

Comment: Your provided code has several problems (typo) related to closing commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the date object at first and then use the `title` yaml key later.

````
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
date_obj <- "2023-04-15 to 2023-05-16"
```

---
title: 'Metrics From `r date_obj`'
---

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````

You can also use parameters too,

````
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
params:
  date_obj: ""
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

---
title: 'Metrics From `r params$date_obj`'
---

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````

Then render the document,

```r
# get your date object
date_obj <- "2023-04-15 to 2023-05-16"

# then render
rmarkdown::render("flex_dashboard.Rmd", params = list(date_obj = date_obj))
```

[image: r code in title]